# Select Distinct Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am having this problem with my database. My code is:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test1]
    @den nchar(14) = ''         
 AS
 BEGIN  
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @SQL AS varchar(3000) = ''   
   DECLARE @WHERE1 AS varchar(1000) = ''    
   DECLARE @ORDERBY1 AS varchar(1000) = ''

   SET @WHERE1 = @WHERE1 + ' WHERE [dbo].table2.sag=1 '

   IF (@den != '')      
      SET @WHERE1 = @WHERE1 + ' AND RIGHT(''0000000000''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[dbo].table1_den_id1),10) +RIGHT(''0000''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),[dbo].table1_den_id2),4) = ''' + RIGHT('00000000000000'+RTRIM(@den),14) + ''''

   SET @ORDERBY1 = @ORDERBY1 + 'GROUP BY [dbo].table2.item_barcord      
ORDER BY LEFT([dbo].table2.item_barcord,13) ASC'

   SET @SQL = @SQL + '      
          SELECT            
          DISTINCT          
          ''JAN'' + LEFT([dbo].table2.item_barcord,13) AS ''code'',             
          LEFT(MIN([dbo].table2.item_name),15) AS ''name''      
          FROM [dbo].table1         
          INNER JOIN [dbo].table2 ON [dbo].table1.id = [dbo].table2.id          '           + @WHERE1       
          + @ORDERBY1

   DECLARE @RET AS numeric(3,0) = 0

   EXEC(@SQL)   
   SET @RET = @@ROWCOUNT

   RETURN @RET
END
```

However I am getting this error:

> *ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.*

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line :

```
SET @ORDERBY1 = @ORDERBY1 + 'GROUP BY [dbo].table2.item_barcord     
ORDER BY LEFT([dbo].table2.item_barcord,13) ASC'
```

To :

```
SET @ORDERBY1 = @ORDERBY1 + 'GROUP BY [dbo].table2.item_barcord     
ORDER BY LEFT([dbo].table2.item_barcord,13), 2 ASC'
```

More: [SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the query so you don't need a `select distinct`:

```
      SELECT ''JAN'' + LEFT([dbo].table2.item_barcord,13) AS ''code'',  
      . . . 
      group by LEFT([dbo].table2.item_barcord,13)
```

Then the `order by` will work right.  As an added bonus, the query will make more sense -- `select distinct` in an aggregation is a bit difficult to figure out.